# Laravel Method Injection - Variable exists?

Tags: php, laravel, variables, methods, laravel-5

Let's say that we have Laravel's default **User.php** model, and we also have **UsersController.php**. Here's how the *create* method looks like:

```
public function create(User $user)
{
    return view('backend.users.form', compact('user'));
}
```

As you can see - **User $user** is passed as argument, and view *backend.users.form* receives that *$user*.

If I add **dd($user);** in the *create* method:

```
public function create(User $user)
{
    dd($user);
    return view('backend.users.form', compact('user'));
}
```

the result will be:

```
User {#193 ▼
  #fillable: array:3 [▼
    0 => "name"
    1 => "email"
    2 => "password"
  ]
  #hidden: array:2 [▼
    0 => "password"
    1 => "remember_token"
  ]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #relations: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
```

So, variable (instance) **$user** exists, right?

But, in a view *backend.users.form* that receives **$user**, if we do something like this:

```
<h3>{!! $user->exists ? 'Editing '.$user->name : 'Create New User' !!}</h3>
```

The result will be as if **$user** does not exist? The result will be *Create New User*. I do not understand it. 
Can you explain to me why **$user->exists** returns **false** when **dd($user);** shows that it exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing your DI-container configuration, the `User` instance you inject probably does not exist as a record in the database - it has no identity. It is merely a model instance you can use.

Comment: Ah, now I see that exists is  Eloquent method and it checks if there is a record in the database... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Can you explain to me why $user->exists returns false when dd($user);
>   shows that it exists?

Please look carefully at the result of `dd()` inside a controller:

```
...
+exists: false
...
```

`$user->exists` is `false` here, so it will return `false` in any case.

Comment: Ah, now I see that exists is Eloquent method and it checks if there is a record in the database... thanks!